# MaaS node deployment failing on HP Proliant DL380 G5

Tags: server, raid, maas, lvm

i have a little lab environment with 3 DL380 G5s.
All of them have 2 disks forming RAID 1+0.
Got one set up as maas controller with ubuntu 14.04 (had no problem using LVM to install Ubuntu on the raid)
Enlisting and comissioning the other 2 servers with LVM  storage layout goes fine.
But when i try to deploy i get errors that mdadm can't find partitons and deploment fails. Maas WebUi has the following message:

```
mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically
An error occured handling 'cciss!c0d0': OSError - [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/sys/block/c0d0/holders'
[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/sys/block/c0d0/holders'
Installation failed with exception: Unexpected error while running command.
Command: ['curtin', 'block-meta', 'custom']
Exit code: 3
Reason: -
Stdout: "mdadm: No arrays found in config file or automatically\nAn error occured handling 'cciss!c0d0': OSError - [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/sys/block/c0d0/holders'\n[Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/sys/block/c0d0/holders'\n"
Stderr: ''
```

Tried with ubuntu 12.04, 14.04 and 15.10.
Can anyone help me to diagnose the problem, as i have no idea what is causing it as installin from a usb stick goes fine on all servers, but cloud istall fails.

Answer (score 1):

I recently run into this issue.
The solution is to disable cciss driver by setting MAAS global kernel parameters.
MAAS has issues when installing HP machines. This is due to old device driver cciss. This gives naming to block devices which MAAS curtin installer cannot handle. Add this to Global kernel parameters in MAAS settings. Use a better hpsa driver.
cciss.blacklist=yes modprobe.blacklist=cciss hpsa.hpsa_allow_any=1

Then release and re commision the node.

Comment: i've added the `cciss.blacklist=yes modprobe.blacklist=cciss hpsa.hpsa_allow_any=1` to Maas kernel parameters via WebUI and re-commissioned the nodes. 
But after blacklisting the cciss driver the commissioning script could not find any hard drives at all

Comment: Maybe try using a more recent boot image.

Answer (score 0):

You must add another param. The complete params are:

> cciss.blacklist=yes modprobe.blacklist=cciss hpsa.hpsa_allow_any=1
>   hpsa.hpsa_simple_mode=1

Regards.

Comment: thank you, i will try that on one of the G5 when i have the opportunity